# Where's the error that causes grey screen? [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got grey screen for some reason in release version. There are no errors shown in terminal, so idk what to change in code. Initially there have been Flexible, Expdanded, and HeroTag errors, but I removed them and the problems didn't show up in debug. But still when I upload app to google play it shows grey screen.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        ....
        heroTag: "btn2",
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding, vertical: 1.5 * kDefaultPadding),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Form',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: kFontTitle,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPadding),
                  child: getImagesGrid()
                ),
                .... (Bunch of TextFields)
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
    );

Widget getImagesGrid(){
    return SizedBox(
      height: 220,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap(
          children: imagefiles!.map((image){
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 7 / 9,
                    child: Image.file(File(image.path))),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: is there any variable that you forgot to declare, especially when you make a variable as `late`? Also there's a high chance that your `imagefiles` is null or empty or wrong format when mapping

Comment: @Nguyenfamily final List<XFile>? imagefiles = [];
I declared it this way, shouldn't there be problems still?

Also in code I use imagefiles != null ? Wrap(

Comment: Is `.... (Bunch of TextFields)` really just TextFields? Are you sure you have no `Expanded` in your code?

Comment: @Ivo yeah, just checked the code, no Expanded